# How to upload image from camera/gallery to firestore database android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I want to upload the image getting from camera of gallery to firestore database. I have got an answer on stackoverflow in which I am creating a temporary file in the storage and uploading it on the firestore. It was working fine but after one month the app started to crash because the file got deleted from the memory. Is there a way using which I can do that?

```
class SellFragment : Fragment() {



    private lateinit var currentUser: FirebaseUser
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        if (container != null) {
            mContext = container.context
        }

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sell, container, false)
        val ivBook: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_book)
        val ivEdit: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_edit)
        val btnPublishBook: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_publishBook)

        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!

        ivBook.setOnClickListener {
            choosePhoto()
        }

        ivEdit.setOnClickListener {
            choosePhoto()
        }

        btnPublishBook.setOnClickListener {
            updateUI()
        }

        return view
    }

    private fun updateUI() {
        val bookName = et_bookName.text.toString()
        val authorName = et_authorName.text.toString()
        val price = et_price.text.toString()

        if(imageUri != null) {

            if (bookName.isNotEmpty() && authorName.isNotEmpty() && price.isNotEmpty()) {
                val book = Book(currentUser.uid, System.currentTimeMillis().toString(), imageUri.toString(), bookName, authorName, price)
                val bookDao = BookDao()
                bookDao.addBook(book)
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Published book successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Empty fields not allowed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select a photo of the book!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun choosePhoto() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
        builder.setMessage("Pick Photo from..")
            .setPositiveButton("Camera",
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
                    choosePhotoFromCamera()

                })
            .setNegativeButton("Gallery",
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
                    choosePhotoFromGallery()
                })

        val alertDialog = builder.create()
        alertDialog.show()
    }

    private fun choosePhotoFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"     // means only image will be selected
        startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Images"),
            HomeActivity.PICK_PHOTO_CODE
        )
    }

    private fun choosePhotoFromCamera() {
        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, HomeActivity.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                HomeActivity.PICK_PHOTO_CODE -> {
                    imageUri = data?.data
                }

                HomeActivity.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                    var photo = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                    //Rotates the photo 90 degree
                    val matrix = Matrix()
                    matrix.postRotate(90F)
                    photo = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.width, photo.height, matrix, true)

                    imageUri = convertBitmapToUri(photo)
                }
            }

            updatePhoto()
        }
    }

    private fun updatePhoto() {
        iv_book.setImageURI(imageUri)
    }

    private fun convertBitmapToUri(photo: Bitmap): Uri? {
        val tempFile = File.createTempFile("temprentpk", ".png")
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes)
        val bitmapData = bytes.toByteArray()

        val fileOutPut = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
        fileOutPut.write(bitmapData)
        fileOutPut.flush()
        fileOutPut.close()
        return Uri.fromFile(tempFile)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).